# Ubuntu 18.04-Replace default screen lock behavior with custom shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, lock-screen

I'd like to override the default Ubuntu screen locking behavior. I have a shell script set up which does exactly what I want it to do when I run it manually, however, I cannot seem to find any way to have it automatically fire on screen lock (whether from timeout, keyboard shortcut, menu option, whatever). Ideally I could also turn off any other behavior from the lock event (so that it just runs my script and nothing else).

Does anyone know if this is possible or how to accomplish it? A few older answers I've found have hinted at using tools like dbus-monitor to listen for lock/unlock events but those don't seem to fire the same way in this version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, more or less:

First, I turned off all default screensaver behavior in System Settings > Screensaver Preferences by unchecking "Activate screensaver when computer is idle" and "Lock screen when screensaver is active". This means Ubuntu will still throw an IdleHint event for lock/unlock, but the system will not do anything when that happens, allowing my custom script to handle screensaver/lock behavior itself.

I then added this script as a startup script under Startup Applications:

```
#use gdbus monitor to listen for idle hints from the current session
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1 | 
( while true
  do read X
  if grep -q "<true>" <<< "$X"; then
    # run custom screensaver behavior on screen lock
    bash /home/tom/.screensaver/screensaver.sh
  elif grep -q "<false>" <<< "$X"; then
    # run any custom unlock behavior, if necessary
  fi
done )
```

Comment: you should take look at `xss-lock`

Comment: tried it, couldn't get it to work on this version of Ubuntu; was missing too many dependencies or something along those lines